# How can I count how many times a controller action is called in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What's the best way to find out how many times a controller action in a CakePHP application is called?

Comment: This is an odd question. It's called as many times the user visits the url... So use a stat tracker like google analytics or stat counter.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need this inside your application, this is just for Debugging (which it sounds like)

I'd set up [XDebug](http://xdebug.org) and [Webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/)

Which will give you the Invocation Count along with the cost of the function.